# WPF Scrollviewer Can't scroll horizontally

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, scrollviewer

I can't find a way to make these images in a scrollviewer horizontally.

They're like this

```
IMAGE1
IMAGE2
IMAGE3
```

I want

```
IMAGE1 IMAGE2 IMAGE3
```

So I can scroll them horizontally. I've already tried google and stackoverflow and I can't find a working solution :(

Code

```
<Window x:Class="TESSTTTTTT.MirrorWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MirrorWindow" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" WindowStyle="None">
    <Grid Name="grid2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Column="0" Name="ColumnKinect">
            <Image Name="camera2" Height="1800" Width="3200" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <!--
        <Canvas Name="canvas2" Height="1800" Width="3200" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Hidden"  />-->
            <Image Name="imgBodyFrame" Source="{Binding MainWindow.ImageSource}" Height="1800" Width="3200"/>
            <!--Stretch="UniformToFill"-->

            <Image Name="img3DBodyRotation" Source="{Binding MainWindow.ImageSource}" Height="1800" Width="3200" Visibility="Hidden"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Height="1800" Width="3200" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="ColumnCatalogo">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" Name="scrollViewerCatalogo" Background="AliceBlue"
                                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                <ItemsControl Grid.Row="0" Name="itemsControl" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <ItemsControl Name="itcCatalogo" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ListBox Width="Auto" Height="Auto" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
                                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
                                        <StackPanel Name="stpProduct" Orientation="Vertical">
                                            <TextBlock Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Text="{Binding Nome}" Foreground="#006b66" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="14" FontWeight="ExtraBold"/>
                                            <Image Width="400" Height="300" Source="{Binding PathImmagine}"/>
                                            <TextBlock Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Foreground="#006b66" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold">
                                            <Run Text="Prezzo a partire da: "/>
                                             <LineBreak/>
                                             <Run Text="{Binding Prezzo}"/>
                                            <Run Text="€"/>
                                            </TextBlock>
                                            <TextBlock Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Text="{Binding Rigidita}" Foreground="Gray" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="20" FontWeight="ExtraBold"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </WrapPanel>
                                </ListBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </ItemsControl>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you are speaking about images, Image1 Image2 Image3. You would have mentioned them in the given code snippet. As I am not sure about the ques, I have added 2 scenarios.

Scenario 1: I could see 3 Image control in the 0th Column. If you need them to be shown horizontally, you could use StackPanel instead of Grid, and can use the Orientation property as Horizontal. or you need to add 3 columns to the 0th Column Grid, and you can add those images respectively.

Scenario 2: and in the 1st Grid, you have a scrollviewer, if you need the image controls to be visible horizontally inside those, the same you could use the Orientation property of StackPanel (stackpanel inside the wrappanel) to Horizontal instead of Vertical.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Content="Button1" Foreground="Red" />
            <Button Content="Button2" Foreground="Red" />
            <Button Content="Button3" Foreground="Red" />
            <Button Content="Button4" Foreground="Red" />
            <Button Content="Button5" Foreground="Red" />
            <Button Content="Button6" Foreground="Red" />

        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, adding a custom panel template to your listbox that is horizontal.

```
        <Window x:Class="TESSTTTTTT.MirrorWindow"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                Title="MirrorWindow" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" WindowStyle="None">
            <Grid Name="grid2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid Grid.Column="0" Name="ColumnKinect">
                    <Image Name="camera2" Height="1800" Width="3200" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <!--
                <Canvas Name="canvas2" Height="1800" Width="3200" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Hidden"  />-->
                    <Image Name="imgBodyFrame" Source="{Binding MainWindow.ImageSource}" Height="1800" Width="3200"/>
                    <!--Stretch="UniformToFill"-->

                    <Image Name="img3DBodyRotation" Source="{Binding MainWindow.ImageSource}" Height="1800" Width="3200" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                </Grid>
                <Grid Grid.Column="1" Height="1800" Width="3200" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="ColumnCatalogo">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" Name="scrollViewerCatalogo" Background="AliceBlue"
                                          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                                          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                        <ItemsControl Grid.Row="0" Name="itemsControl" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <ItemsControl Name="itcCatalogo" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
<ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <ListBox Width="Auto" Height="Auto" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">
                                            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
                                                <StackPanel Name="stpProduct" Orientation="Vertical">
                                                    <TextBlock Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Text="{Binding Nome}" Foreground="#006b66" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="14" FontWeight="ExtraBold"/>
                                                    <Image Width="400" Height="300" Source="{Binding PathImmagine}"/>
                                                    <TextBlock Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Foreground="#006b66" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold">
                                                    <Run Text="Prezzo a partire da: "/>
                                                     <LineBreak/>
                                                     <Run Text="{Binding Prezzo}"/>
                                                    <Run Text="€"/>
                                                    </TextBlock>
                                                    <TextBlock Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Text="{Binding Rigidita}" Foreground="Gray" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="20" FontWeight="ExtraBold"/>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </WrapPanel>
                                        </ListBox>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Window>
```